# Angular 2 default value in view

Tags: angular

I would like to give a default value of a variable in my view if it's empty or not defined :

```
<p>{{(person | async)?.name}}</p>
```

If the field `name` is empty, i would like to see this :

```
<p>Default value</p>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `||`operator

```
<p>{{(person | async)?.name || 'Default value'}}</p>
```

Comment: @user7867717 no worries. make sure to mark as answer if this helped