# Assign 0 to template if no value is present

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind a 0 to my html template if there is no value present from an endpoint.
So I have the below in my HTML

```
${{ amount }}
```

If amount is not available I would like to show `$0` to the user. Is this possible to do in the HTML template or do I have to do a check in my TS file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139331/angular-2-default-value-in-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Angular template interpolations](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) are Typescript expressions. So you could use the `||` operator

```html
${{ amount || 0 }}
```